# github pages doesn't display css for index.html but display for others

Tags: html, css, github-pages

I read different questions on `stackoverflow` regarding this issue but i haven't got any solution for my case, the rest of my pages are displaying css well, but `index.html` doesn't display. 
But surprisingly when i run my project locally it works very well.

What am i missing?

**My github pages link :**

https://huxaiphaer.github.io/-Ride-My-Way/index.html

**My github project link , in the branch *gh-pages*:**

https://github.com/huxaiphaer/-Ride-My-Way/tree/gh-pages

Comment: Reference your file from the root. You may have to change your reference before moving from local.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `href` was wrong for your css import. You were navigating up more folder.

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="UI/css/index.css">
```

Comment: Thanks @TobiasGeiselmann , but still my question stands , why is it working locally in the previous structure.

Comment: That depends on what your file structure looks like. I guess it's not exactly the same on your local machine.